# Spring Cloud Stream - modify DLQ messages

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using Spring Cloud Stream's DLQ feature with the Kafka binder. When message processing fails, the message is sent to the DLQ as expected, however, I want to be able to modify the message being sent to the DLQ to include some extra diagnostic information. The problem is the messages sent to the DLQ are the *original* messages; any mutations I have made are ignored. My approach to solve this so far has been to intercept the message before it is sent to the DLQ and add extra info which is stored in another bean. Specifically, I have tried these two approaches:

1. **Solution**: implement a plain Kafka `ProducerInterceptor` for the DLQ. **Problem**: the implementation is instantiated outside of the Spring Context and so I cannot inject other beans which I need. Spring Kafka have documented [this solution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/897), however, it requires creating a new `ProducerFactory` bean, which means I can't use the bean from underlying Spring Cloud Stream.
2. **Solution**: implement a Spring `ChannelInterceptor`. **Problem**: I cannot get a reference to the message channel for the DLQ, nor the underlying channel name, so I cannot configure the interceptor for DLQ messages only.

Any ideas on how this could be solved?

Answer (score 1):

> Problem: I cannot get a reference to the message channel for the DLQ, nor the underlying channel name, so I cannot configure the interceptor for DLQ messages only.

The error channel name is

```
destinationName.group.errors
```

You can get it as an `AbstractMessageChannel` from the application context...

```
context.getBean("destinationName.group.errors", AbstractMessageChannel.class)
```

...and add the interceptor.

Alternatively, don't use the binder's DLQ mechanism at all and add your own error handler:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "destinationName.group.errors")
void errors(Message<?> error) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using a custom DLQ topic name; I'll see if this still works. Using a custom DLQ mechanism would be great but the project already has dependencies on Spring's so I'm stuck with that.

Comment: Hmm, can't get a reference to the DLQ channel with that example. The only `AbstractMessageChannel` in the context is `errorChannel`, and that is receiving `MessagingException` messages, not the outbound DLQ messages. I've also checked the context for `MessageChannel` beans and I don't see it their either.

Comment: You have to wait until the binding is registered; you can't just auto wire it; you can add a `SmartLifecycle` `@Bean` put it in a later (higher) 'phase` than the phase the binding is created in (which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000`). `autoStartup` must be `true` so that Spring will call the `start()` method (which is where you should put your code).